# Help with solving minimisation problems using primal simplex method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

I am trying to understand how to solve minimisation problems using primal simplex method and somehow I understand the steps, just that the final result is not correct. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I have tried searching the net for detailed steps but I don't understand them. Precisely my problem is the tableau, I set it up (with slack variables) and I start by finding the pivot column that is smallest number in the objective function variables row, then I find the pivot row and then I make sure that the numbers in the pivot column (except the pivot number) are 0. I continue doing this until there are no negative numbers in the objective function row. It seems that doing these steps I can't find the correct result.

The problem is the following:

$$
z=-2x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3
$$
s.t
$$x_1 + x_2 - 2x_3 \geq 1$$
$$x_1 + x_2 - x_3 \leq 3$$
$$-x_1 - x_2 +3x_3 \geq -2$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$$

EDIT:
[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFCYQ.jpg)

Comment: Without your work, we can't assess what you did wrong. Edit your original post to include this.

Comment: I edited my post.